# How to change value of Slider throught input value

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
  document.getElementById("myRangeValue").value = "Rs: " + slider;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper Slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10000000" value="20000" name="myRange" id="myRange" onchange="myFunction()" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</div>

<div class="wrapper SliderValue">
  <input type="text" name="myRangeValue" value="Rs.0" id="myRangeValue" style="height:50px;text-align: center;font-size: 25px;">
</div>
```

since when i am scrolling the slider, the value in the input box changes but How can i change the value of the slider by giving input value ??

suppose input value = 50000
so,
value of the slider also changes to 50000 without scrolling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update html5 range on change of a text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475016/how-to-update-html5-range-on-change-of-a-text-input)

Comment: Create another function similar to `myFunction` and set the `myRange` value to `myRangeValue` value (After replacing `"Rs. "` from the value)

Comment: myRangeValue.value = foo;

Answer (score 0):

Given your slider inputs here:

```
<div class="wrapper Slider">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10000000" value="20000" class="slider " name="myRange" id="myRange" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</div>
<div class="wrapper SliderValue">  
    <input type="text" class="personal" name="myRangeValue" value="Rs.0"  id="myRangeValue" style="height:50px;text-align: center;font-size: 25px;">
</div>
```

you could use the following javascript to update after hitting return in the myRangeValue inout box.

```
    document.getElementById('myRange').addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
        document.getElementById('myRangeValue').value = document.getElementById('myRange').value;
    });

    document.getElementById('myRange').addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
        document.getElementById('myRangeValue').value = document.getElementById('myRange').value;
    });

    document.getElementById('myRangeValue').addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode !== undefined) { // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode
            switch(event.keyCode) {
                case 13: // return key
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('myRange').value = document.getElementById('myRangeValue').value;
                    break;
                default:
                    // console.log('event.keyCode: ' + event.keyCode)
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's a jsfiddle that demos the code above
[Change slider value](https://jsfiddle.net/15hr0py2/)